# How to identify Omnibox IAccessible child object in Google Chrome independently from UI language?

Tags: delphi, google-chrome, delphi-xe2, ole, iaccessible

Using Delphi XE2 with OleAcc, I am able to transverse all IAccessible child objects of a Google Chrome window and get their NAME and VALUE with `get_AccName` and `get_AccValue` respectively, to search for the Omnibox control which contains the URL as IAccessible VALUE. Unfortunately, the IAccessible NAME in Chrome is localized, so in Chrome with German UI language, to identify the Omnibox control, I have to use the IAccessible NAME "Adress- und Suchleiste", which works well with German UI language in Chrome. This IAccessible NAME is different for each Chrome UI language, so to identify the Omnibox control with all Chrome UI languages, I would have to compare all Chrome IAccessible child objects with all localized IAccessible NAME variations of the Omnibox control. So my question is:

Is there an other method to identify the Omnibox IAccessible child object independently from the UI language?

I've used MS Inspect.exe to see all IAccessible properties of the Omnibox child object in Chrome, but did not find anything which seemed useful for this purpose.